# Facebook has trouble seeing changes to a dynamic page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've got a page that displays a video of the day. The URL looks like this:

http://www.domain.com/vod/?date=12/14/2013

Where the date specifies the date for the video of the day.

The problem is that when I share this, Facebook doesn't see the difference in the date as a being a different page. The result is that it outputs the wrong thumbnail image for the page.

The page is fully open-graph compatible. I can clear facebook's cache by using the open graph debugger, which helps, but when I try to share the page on FB, it picks up older cached versions of the page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by doing a URL Rewrite... since the video of the day records have an ID, I am outputting the ID in the request string that will be shared. On the server, I'm rewriting the URL to point to the vodeo of the day directory and I'm ignoring the ID.

This is the URL that my site wants to see:

http://www.domain.com/vod/?date=12/14/2013

I'm now sharing this URL:

http://www.domain.com/vod/108/?date=12/14/2013 (notice the additional directory 108)

And I'm rewriting it to the first URL. I'm using the URL Rewrite module in IIS.